# How to permanently disable "reopen windows"?

Tags: mac, shutdown, restart

I *never* want to login and be bombarded with the old windows I had open last time I was using my Mac. It is distracting and it is counter to my understanding that the computer is here to serve me, not the other way around.

My Mac is set to automatically shutdown at night. So there is no way for me to uncheck the "restore windows" box when I shut down. I don't ever want the checkbox because I never want this "feature".

How can I banish this "feature" from my Mac?

[image: u]

Comment: Can you not do a manual shutdown for some reason?

Comment: This is a duplicate. I’m on my phone so I can’t find the original question but Gummibando has the correct answer too.

Answer (score 5):

Just disable the corresponding checkbox in the "regular" shutdown dialog (hold the power button for a few seconds). The setting is carried over to the auto-shutdown dialog.

[image]